How they enter class D airspace at KOPF?
I noticed KOPF (Miami Opa Locka Executive) is class D but surrounded with huge class B of Miami international airport. How does the OPF ATC vector an aircraft without radaring through transponder? or do they have a radar service even though KOPF is class D

Towers don't generally vector aircraft. They may or may not have a radar, but their primary means of providing services are visual and procedural. If they want you in a specific place in their airspace, they will generally give landmarks (e.g. "stay west of the freeway") or traffic pattern instructions (e.g. "enter left downwind runway 1") or something else besides assigning you specific headings.
While in the surrounding class B/C you will generally be talking to an approach controller who does have a radar. Although if you look at the chart carefully you'll see it's actually possible to get to KOPF without entering class B or C airspace.
